End of sentence dot moves before bold text when using vim-pandoc
Using Vim-Pandoc, I'm having a strange behavior change with Pandoc bold toggle:
- <localleader>b     toggles bold

For example
some text.

When I select "some" and press <localleader>b, I correctly get:
**some** text.

But when I select "text", I get the dot move before the bold text:
some .**text**

This used to work before, how can I correct this? Any idea why that could be the case?

looks like a bug to me

Use the plugin's issue tracker.
